# Command to create a new project using gatsby not working

Tags: gatsby

I am creating a project called "new-app". After installing gatsby successfully, I tried to run the command "gatsby new my-app". I always get an error which states:

> ERROR eating new site from git:
>   https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
>
> Command failed with exit code 2 (ENOENT): git clone
>   https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git my-app
>   --single-branch spawn git ENOENT
>
> Error: Command failed with exit code 2 (ENOENT): git clone
>   https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git my-app
>   --single-branch   spawn git ENOENT
>
> - enoent.js:6 notFoundError
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[cross-spawn]/lib/enoent.js:6:26
> - enoent.js:40 verifyENOENT
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[cross-spawn]/lib/enoent.js:40:16
> - enoent.js:27 ChildProcess.cp.emit
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[cross-spawn]/lib/enoent.js:27:25
> - child_process.js:248 Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>     internal/child_process.js:248:12

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this myself. I wiped my laptop last week and completely forgot to install git. Problem solved (for me anyway, hopefully for you too!)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this worked perfectly for me.
Just install GIT from: https://git-scm.com/download/win

I set it to use windows CMD.

Comment: `winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget` this one command fixed the issue for me on windows

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the gatsby CLI *first* before creating your gatsby project?

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Comment: I have already done it. I have even reinstalled it, but also I get this error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed Git for Windows to use the MinTTY terminal, and I was trying to run `gatsby new` from Windows Command Prompt. Since Git was not configured for cmd, the command failed.  Ran the command at a Git Bash (MinTTY) prompt and the command worked.

Answer (score 0):

JMLima's answer is correct, but the language was not really helpful. The simple answer would be:

1. Install Git
2. Set up PATH variables on Windows

These two steps should solve your issue.
Link to download Git: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download and Install Git (As others just said)
2. Open Git CMD & Get the exact path of your Project folder
3. Run the command

Answer (score 0):

1.First Install Git
https://git-scm.com/downloads

2.Use Git Bash Termianl

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vs-code Editor then use integrated git-bash in terminal and run the gatsby installation command OR you can also use git terminal to use gatsby commands

Answer (score 0):

Git wasn't installed in my case.
Installed Git for windows but the problem persisted.
Used Git CMD for the same command, which then ran perfectly.
Thanks.

Comment: "*Used Git CMD for the same command*" -> can you give more details how what you did exactly?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Encountered this.... running as administrator fixed it

Comment: This answer adds absolutely nothing to current answers, why post it at all?

Comment: Yes it's a resolution which had yet to be mentioned. it may save people from unnecessarily reinstalling stuff.. like I did.